# Determine if 3d coordinate is inside frustum

Tags: c++, 3d, coordinates

I am trying to implement an overlay for a particular screen saver that I inject my application into.
This screen saver uses 3d objects and a dynamic camera.

I have camera position and direction and the 3d object positions, and the fov value, and I'd like to create an audio based overlay that adds icons to the objects.

I have the 2d overlay in place, and can successfully iterate the objects, however I can't figure how to calculate a frustum with the data I have.

Basically: how can one create a frustrum from the camera direction? Is a world to screen matrix required to create the frustum? I don't have the w2s matrix, so would that make the problem impossible to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an excellent resource at http://web.archive.org/web/20120531231005/http://crazyjoke.free.fr/doc/3D/plane%20extraction.pdf  which should explain everything you need and outlines how to extract the view frustum using the view and model matrices.

In regards to the world to screen (W2S) matrix you can calculate it on the fly by utilising a variant of the following:

`ScreenPosition = (ProjectionMatrix* (ViewMatrix * WorldPosition))`

Thast way you can calculate it on the fly as required.

There is also a frustum tutorial at [Lighthouse](http://zach.in.tu-clausthal.de/teaching/cg_literatur/lighthouse3d_view_frustum_culling/) aimed at frustum culling, but explaining the implementation quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks, but that paper seems to explain the relation, and calculations, related to the w2s matrix. What I can't find if it's at all possible to create a frustrum from camera direction / position -without- the w2s matrix of the scene.

Comment: Think you would always need the world to screen matrix to be able to check what should and should not be on-screen based on a frustum which is based on camera position and orientation, as you will need to convert between screen space and world space (or vice versa) to find out what is actually in view.  You could calculate the w2s matrix on the fly when you need it though.